# how to add validation to a reactjs form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsform

I have developed a registration form and I tried using validation format but it is not working. I don't know how and where to code a function for it and apply it. please help me how to do it. I will attach the code i have done till now.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

export default function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [Employee_name, setEmployee_name] = useState('');
    const [Employee_id, setEmployee_id] = useState('');
    const [Employee_address, setEmployee_address] = useState('');
    const [Employee_post, setEmployee_post] = useState('');



    const postData = () => {

        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/qo`, {
            Employee_name,
            Employee_id,
            Employee_address,
            Employee_post

        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/read')
        })
        alert('Data Saved')
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Name</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Name' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_name(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee ID</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee ID' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_id(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Address</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Address' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_address(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Position</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Position' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_post(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Check out this: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

This could help you solve the form validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are good libraries out there, that can help you with form validation before allowing a user to submit the form.

One such library could be formik together with Yup.

This is how I do client side form validation on my forms:

Login schema (made with Yup):

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';


const loginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
        .min(3, 'Minimum 3 chars')
        .max(50, 'Max 50 chars')
    /* password: Yup.string()
        .min(6, 'Minimum 6 chars')
        .max(50, 'Max 50 chars')
    */
});
```

Login component:

```
export const Login = () => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            username: ''
        },
        validationSchema: loginSchema,

        onSubmit: async (values, {setStatus, setSubmitting}) => {
            setLoading(true);
            setStatus(null);

            try {

                  // Call your API function to post to the backend here
                  // You can access your form values in the "values" parameter

                    setLoading(false);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                setStatus('User not found');
                setSubmitting(false);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }
    });

}

return (
        <form
            onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
            className={'auth-form-wrapper'}
        >

            {/* begin::Heading */}
            <div className={'auth-form-header'}>
                <h1>Log in</h1>
                <div className={'auth-error-message-container'}>
                        formik.status && (
                            <p className={'error-message'}>{formik.status}</p>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* end::Heading */}

            {/* begin::Form group content */}
            <div className={'auth-form-content'}>
                {/* begin::Form group */}
                <div className={'dynamic-input-container'}>
                    <input type='text'
                           id="username"
                           value={formik.values.username}
                           onChange={formik.handleChange}
                           placeholder='Username'
                           className={'dynamic-input auth-input ' + clsx(
                               {'is-invalid': formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username},
                               {
                                   'is-valid': formik.touched.username && !formik.errors.username
                               }
                           )}
                           autoComplete='off'
                    />

                    {formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username && (
                        <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
                            <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.username}</span>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                {/* end::Form group*/}

                {/* begin::Action */}
                <div className='auth-btn-container'>
                    <Button variant="contained" size="medium" type={'submit'} disabled={loading}>
                        {
                            !loading ? <span>Continue</span>
                                :
                                (
                                    <span className={'auth-spinner-container'}>
                        <ClipLoader
                            loading={loading}
                            size={20}
                            aria-label='Loading Spinner'
                        />
                        </span>
                                )
                        }
                    </Button>
                </div>
                {/* end::Action */}
            </div>
            {/* end::Form group content */}

        </form>
    );
```

Please note, that in my example I only have a "username" input, but you can obviously add as many fields as you wish.

Documentation:

Formik: https://formik.org/docs/tutorial

Yup: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup

clxs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

export default function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [Employee_name, setEmployee_name] = useState('');
    const [Employee_id, setEmployee_id] = useState('');
    const [Employee_address, setEmployee_address] = useState('');
    const [Employee_post, setEmployee_post] = useState('');



    const postData = e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         
         if(Employee_name.length == 0) return false;
         if(Employee_id.length == 0) return false;
         if(Employee_address.length == 0) return false;
         if(Employee_post.length == 0) return false;
         
        
        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/qo`, {
            Employee_name,
            Employee_id,
            Employee_address,
            Employee_post

        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/read')
        })
        alert('Data Saved')
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form" onSubmit={e => postData(e)}>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Name</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Name' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_name(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee ID</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee ID' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_id(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Address</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Address' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_address(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Position</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Position' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_post(e.target.value)} required={true}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is updated code from your snippet. try this and let me know what's the progress.

I really appreciate you.

Comment: It worked thanks sir just added alert  in your edited code thanks for the help sir now i can continue with the learning now I am making a login page